# check if application installed on system

Tags: c#, registry

I want to check if the program is installed on the user's system or not I've used registry to do this, and the program works well

But now I want to check the version number

```
return uninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames()
                               .Select(installedSoftwareString => uninstallKey.OpenSubKey(installedSoftwareString))
                               .Select(installedSoftwareKey => installedSoftwareKey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string)
                               .Any(installedSoftwareName => installedSoftwareName != null && installedSoftwareName.Contains(softwareName));
```

To do this, I added the following code

```
.Select(installedSoftwareKey => installedSoftwareKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion") as string)
```

But it gives an error

> string does not contain a definitaion for GetValue...

Comment: `installedSoftwareName` is string already

Comment: Isn't the installed software version specified in the `VersionMajor` and `VersionMinor` and *condensed* in the `Version` DWORD Key values?

Comment: Btw, `installedSoftwareKey.GetValue("DisplayName")` then `installedSoftwareName != null && installedSoftwareName.ToString().Contains(softwareName)`. But you should probably access the Values previously mentioned.

Comment: @Jimi yes i forget to remove that code, anyway how can i check 2 value with select

Comment: Select is a *transformation* function, you can create an anonymous object that contains the values you need. E.g., `.Select(installedSoftwareKey => new { Name = installedSoftwareKey.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString(), VerMajor = (int?)installedSoftwareKey.GetValue("VersionMajor"), VerMinor = (int?)installedSoftwareKey.GetValue("VersionMinor")`. But be aware that not all softwares specify (create) these values, so `NullReferenceException` must be handled (or avoided, prefiltering).

Comment: Or, avoid reading the Registry directly entirely and use instead the [Installer functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/inventory-products-and-patches-?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to extract this information. [WMI is another option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-software-installations?view=powershell-7), but it's quite slow.